# ASP.NET GridView DropDownList Posts Empty Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble with a DropDownList within a GridView that posts a NULL value when in fact a value is selected from the list when using inline editing.

The problem is that I can't use this method to bind the value to the UpdateCommand in my SqlDataSource:

SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Value") %>'

The reason for this is because the value might not exist in the list so it throws an exception.

Is there a way I can bind the value to the UpdateCommand without using SelectedValue?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You may use RowDataBound to set SelectedValue;

in .cs file

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
    DropDownList DropDownList1 = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList);
    HiddenField HiddenField1 = (e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField);
    DropDownList1.SelectedValue = HiddenField1.Value;

}
```

in .aspx file;

```
    <Columns>

...

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("Value") %>'></asp:HiddenField>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                ...
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```